# Pattern gets shifted when painting at the bottom edge of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, graphics

I would like to paint a repeating grass pattern at the bottom of a canvas. The image does repeat, but it's vertically shifted.

The pattern is based on a 192x50 image:

[image: grass image]

I've noticed that if I paint from the y-coordinates 50, 100, 150, and so on, the pattern is displayed correctly. It doesn't work at other coordinates.

The resulting canvas has a vertically shifted grass pattern:

[image: shifted pattern]

I don't know why it gets shifted like that.

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display: block;">  
</canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
// Grass Background Image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true; 
};
bgImage.src = "img/grass.png";
```

I do the following in a loop:

```
if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage,0, canvas.height -50,192,50);
        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(bgImage, "repeat"); // Create a pattern with this image, and set it to repeat".
        ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height - bgImage.height,canvas.width, 50); // context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that the pattern is calculated starting from the top left corner of the canvas. If you paint starting at a canvas y-coordinate that isn't an integer multiple of the image height, the visible portion of the pattern won't start at the top of the image.

To fix this, shift the drawing context down before painting with the pattern, then paint the pattern at a location shifted up, then shift the context back up:

```
  var shiftY = canvas.height % image.height;
  context.translate(0, shiftY);
  context.fillRect(0, canvas.height - image.height - shiftY,
                   canvas.width, image.height);
  context.translate(0, -shiftY);
```

Run the snippet below to see a demonstration. The canvas height is 120, which means that we start painting from the y-coordinate 120 - 50 = 70, which is not a multiple of 50.

To correct for this, we shift the context down by 120 % 50 = 20 and then shift the painting location up by 20. Thus, the pattern gets painted on the shifted context at the y-coordinate (70 - 20) = 50, which is a multiple of the image height.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 120;
canvas.width = 500;

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bfPb.png';
image.onload = function () {
  var pattern = context.createPattern(image, "repeat");
  context.fillStyle = pattern;
  var shiftY = canvas.height % image.height;
  context.translate(0, shiftY);
  context.fillRect(0, canvas.height - image.height - shiftY,
                   canvas.width, image.height);
  context.translate(0, -shiftY);
};
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Let me make one more observation. The loop in your code is inefficient and the `bgReady` flag is unnecessary because you can run the painting code in the `image.onload` function, as I have done in my snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions and your code. It works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put your code in jsFiddle and it seems to work as expected:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
// Grass Background Image
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(bgImage,0, canvas.height -50,192,50);
        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(bgImage, "repeat"); // Create a pattern with this image, and set it to repeat".
        ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height - bgImage.height,canvas.width, 50); // context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
};
bgImage.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMYAAAAzCAYAAADMxHf3AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAABbNSURBVHhe7ZzJch3JdYb9FO4mCYAAMQ8cJG/ssBWywxFsTnoCNkESw72YSUpbh7pBgJjvxTyR7PYbeuOdNun/O5mnmEChFaLVYthdtTiRWVk5nP8vnCGz6uLv/uu//xRyub3xm3Bv71/D3dZvw739fwt3278Nd7Z+Y0L72Lt/Nrm9/i9F+bn9WcNL+vk9xvo8jM3no70Ym3Q0OVTfrL9dI36fNpeszdaScO36Fuu4fklo4x59uec4vC/trneN/+fFXwjXqe3n1t1L2twOrjQMhE6uqA90BQqgKwn0Z/b3axPWy0rGm5IJeE6KrZPW8H4m/sfhfS/9sRRzXepnuroemdCftdDd+/gcdo9+6b7pjV7olHTjmr41/r8ev5d/S91d6O92UDKMYrAvlIBeAJjAjXz3TxdB/oX9L4/xNoTx6OCSP9iiLRFjhCWijDi/9rb8XtbmcyBGEHpIZ9eL+5R+jxLxcdS99L4uNf6fGf8X1J353Q7KhpEpZoO5TmBzACZ4AMnn9i/qWTukoZzNleYoCJH4GnbvUt360NdJ9HqSX538+6f2fK40R06O6+DEUbq4Lojfz/WxNq6Zs8b/CV+G83Pxf1HdVbodXGkY1imVLEYJAOoFmEw+t7+1JzJcaDMRocxVABEhDoJ5SwSpvejPH4KXTqbXU3l5nIvr7uJzUqKTzYuk9f2ej83nqPH/vPi/pO5uByXDYFAOkIn9+qcAfm7/0eVPhAz/8R+LOn0Y62IAnIyMEAOYiPI+DrggEvE2rzvBaR57CGluX5M218PvFfMkudxu42r8xXi/zrEj/xv8X1J3xO3g6lSKhdWZhaxMkoMEoJef2x8SnBwnhtL7Mh9KGpCkz58DWlzzR0F5icyiPas7Efncpr9jUEk/7l8oU9+8Hanx/23wf0ndmdPt4MrNty9cAifxNoABkvJz+0PEVWJ9GCMlvUQfQOTiAC+0Z8RZyR+F/4F4m8qcGLuGmERKjoPSifN2G+frSFyPfJzjdqnx/3X4v6TulG4HJcOgA2KLps5+zUSFUtmkrgRK0hcCrIQc1a1M4gRQ+j0nzb2H9/U5nQRft6izbgKYgy4EXf/MH4ePdRyuv+OlrPFXC7/bwZWplE+UE2PkpEnowyRez0vaDZiAFgQkoC5OihNC6aQUhEp8/QJYEl/P9SnuORlODKR4W35f4uMMC9jSfJTex9entD41/mLtXyJ+SreDnzQM72gisIi3WymlrD27zz0jR20GTqBdcjKoI06I9UmE+VzF2ml+5i4RkfSwek6K30/EGJY0B+3UjVwwpDXsmjVSHxuTrY94u5U1/tie3efe/2f8iNvBlamUg/POhWIsoHYvXQDlfSi9DeA5EU6Mtzkpdg8iJb424mtTAqJEgsTBFpITk/eDhEw30zlbp7Ru3l7jrwR+5nI7KBkGA2wSBiWlqLsCXvf2ywtcXhzQEAEBTkxR0od2lVz7WFcyvzZwajOCki4FUS6XiMjFdXTdvMyF9SiL/jX+SuFnHbeDn9x8O3BKq0tJUwyF1e6liy2W+uTkABiBIPMMiRRvq71mjf//En63g7JhaCADbBIGJaWouwJe9/bLC1xeHNAQAQFOTFHSh3aVXPtY5slJ5trAqc0ISroURLlcIiIX19F18zKXGn+18bsdXB0xUCYphLiChXLZIkxWkJHE+qd7l8EXcsV1MWeq+3o+P+s6aBfTJa15oT0RaGOZV31Yx9fwh+UPydZE/9S3qEtq/NXB73Zw5R4DcXCuYK4c9b6Feya9c3dN6FeAzKRYWHWUsfZ07W2EU/pRt3l0n3UcbF6/DN71Ypz1kcfw/n6PkrVyHVnL9bEykeP3GU9/hPE+V43/l43f7eBqw1AHJjFJi1qZ6n1LF0nxOqWPcwV8PgfO9VV9uGckpuv+N78OA3/4h4tECHB+jRQPLCOOsf7gXGzeBJ6663NBJ83j/VzHGn+18LsdlAzDlSsUTySZAip9oYlH18KLh9fC+IMOlR3W5kQVSlBmdZs7KUcd8XUojdxEOuD6X0eArG1eICMGIlwvFycHQm2eNJcL/QHvOjkxeCzuuU6uj/fzdSh9rhr/LxO/20HJMOjogxwAE7GwLzb56LqRMf7gRniu8qXJdSOpIEdjHXQuroyLKZv65SCmHn0VGo+/sjrzOSgnhDpymTRImX78dWg+uRamHl8LkxKubV7pTn/TJWHLcUKQX+ft9K/xVwO/20E5lUqk5MIglEHB5pOvjJRJeYxxlS+Sx4ie40Z4dl/kzERyctDM4YpQ+jpOGIozD2CefXPD5pt49HX49v4Nm4/79GM+wDk5RlQiiD54meknmkf6MRc6QfDEw6/tHsRRFrpJD4S66VPjL3C7VAm/28GVhuEA3IMYUMlLhU6sj0V35/vC9uxA2GgOha3ZYd27EV58c92APJcngRjEgKfFqRdkJGUo6QeoSSn/Qp7nqeYYf3DdSIagp/c7rc+t5u0LhLhwTTtzTImUaXkLSMaTTWi+CdP7K9MdUhAbx1xJB9ePssZfXfxuByXDoCPKQw6KGCmAVIn1MfnBQk/YnB0Km83BsNYYDjuz/WFzpj+8U30cUCLouYA5YJtHdfcUViZyfA1yVoiYMi/REd5Oj2rOoQRQhD/oKvRgTsRBIoTJ6SfXLYS25obD+uxoaM8PhN25W1ZOal4Im/0dBClEqz+EooeXVq/xVxq/20HJMHIiEBQfV2h7/kD5mibfm+8VIf1hS0pvz0VytmYGws5Mn7yHyJkeVni9Vlipg2BOJwgp2rUGXmH8QafGD4rkPpEyFN41R+WRhsL6zKhIu2GhG/FxACs2aNRVNp9E8PsL/aE1P6yyLxwu9kpuhf3FfnuoTREz+7u//zQPOlzSp8ZfXfxuB2XDSACQb7+5aQqzyeIEYkvAW3N9IqJfShNK+w0I9X0RtjPTG9Ybg2FDRBHC2PhAEqEVy/e5c6We3u+Kazy8KS80Yt7HyFG/t417ImZEoXrINnnjD7vCM5E48TjmtZOPr4eGiJh4RPhUyFT74VK/kXC4JJ0WB8KRSNkTQbtzalf4n5ZO5J6QxPoQ6sRQ1virjd/toGQYT7/p1uanS+VNA/Rc4ZPQBsCWFG7N9VqJh9iWtGa51uLzPVq8N7QlhK8dKWL5nawcwSsQil887AwvBQQQ4w+7E/ldYbl5L6w27yh8DstbjIiU22FV3mKtOSaix8KKSshAYt6YyJE3eSHCJh7f1Jqj4UBknCz2hOOlW+FYJWRszQzq4ckbSac9eRO8SCN5D0rmeS79nt7vrvFXHL/bQckwnklJFEWeyZKfK4ziETYbENCr/FKhSTlmW3UjQqTQjrfYm+ux/LM93x8ORBQkkW9aKJZAOBu3F486I0BKydbcSFibuaPwNxjDoECsNu5aGH0nz4HHgLRd3SesfhJOMa6btyCE7i4MCvhQOH7VG46Wesxb7C4Oiix0H5JegyrlkeYGzNPgOfBqzMXm8VvpV+OvNn63g5JhELI4GcC627KwlsQ8wAybmFsC3h2OF27KGrvDvtq3m9FzkGduyzKPRMzhfLeRB2FrDYVdhd715pCIxtrZwKEQVn/DLHhPRBJG9xa0WZLyW9o8bWjztD5323LF6DWGdK8/tNVnXw/nQKCP5BUOFDKPBHxP43ZEzIGIOFzsU5nCqeZHuGYdSCc3Zl08GcSQu6ITUuOvNn63g5JhEMrI8ziOI28kj9wXIfvyBvsCfJC8wr4I2k0hdH8BwqSo6idLkbSW+u2JuFXlnDFv7JXlR9CbIpG58Toou6f5UZQQBzl4kPa8NnazwwIyoDlGw/L0qFl6a35A9wYsTB6KmNYCmyzpKDIod0XkgerMBZF4EYjYUTvkg4ewytw8TObfkRwxn8bV+KuN3+2gZBgswMkD4Ak7hEM2Q3iNI5FxsnhThEBST9hqyIsI3KGIMGJscrxFtxFBqMVbIHgPCGgJnLVLmUNdHy91m2digwQZR7LyFqQoX+RUYkObLzZgq9NjRhAgtwWKsIhEj4PX6DYPwuaL/PJE86IPG7EteZ9NCV5nszkQ3jVG7DQFoiEleiDhFOE1/mrjdzu40jB2pfCegOIJqJtnEDEAPhYxeA/fcJFLmgcx4nrCqe7Tl3wTwJDCRi2Sok2bSAYMx31tEQ+AE/LBpd5w+kqAJByvtbWJ2lQoJcd8O31HOaiACdyarmMuqU2Wxu2ZZ8BD9IWzV13h/NVNzdMV3r/uMILwIuixq7U35A03GyJmelihPQqpAvdZ80xja/zVxu92UDIMFD1TOMTyAUlYxKoJkVjl2VKnFhFZRkS3AY73FE4Vaul/mvoSLmmPoVQkyTptYyYLxUNwzkx9V5ZKnohADtd4hR15BzZgq817AnG7OLUgTzzUOIAzPzrvK7c8krf4+KYrfHzdKWI6jZTWHCRCHF6sT6TIa2jueAwYN2aH+gOAmFMRU+OvNn63g5JhAIiNEwuevxZA1U/UZouLBO4RRrE0SsIQk0LOD286JJ1W/6jyvZQ8fY3SKBgtnPzPLFlt1PEU5697wpkEb8GJws78iKx7TF7iblgRKYRPQuvuAqBGFGqHzWscQyI5przL6auecP5G81BqzffSnTyTe4RovBRErzUIxcp1Rc62cllSgGPpdaYxhwq9Nf5q43c7KBkG1k7HeNwFCRx1Yd1YdAydhFDPQwlfhKD//EO0UkoXyGHBD69FkM0HgT0GCM9wmgjByrmmvrc4pM3XaGgL+I4UXzeCRgWM/JfNV9xstQSSXJR28kpIeS/58CaSwgOB9OhVlNNq00dOaqRoXoQQfKL7kMoD2Z6Rx6rxVxq/28GVEYMQef5Klq9Q+l6gyCsJkxzV7c7G8NlWzoZnwJP8+PtOgRcxGvNRud0Pv++wNiNtSfmeSsg5R3QNkVwfS/HoQTj7luKy/tbCiAhQLqprNkdbCoV4Jyw7vuInf+XbHLzHkNp7NRaPIc+k++/fpDxZxO7pHg+CUxDyyW3NtdYcVX6rjZv0hyTyS/rZm9wmD7/GX2X8bgclw+BFzaGIANDxYqcIApRA6vp0sUubLIVVlZDEZgzwEAIRhNKzRJCTBRGQAIFOImTTZmAgQdaPRbPZ2pJwggBhKI9VsxGEnBiyOfno0RgI44UQpxkKl7rPXHgV2vAseD08HnNABp8y8FaVM/WtZjyRwBtazjzLZpHz+hp/lfG7HZQMY1NWg3cAPB7jxIBBTId5Ecg5WaCd/BOwbHY6wnuVgKbPufqzATpTHRI4KTCiyDtFJPcAdyJi8BacN7PJAszqzK8MNKcM5KW80ocUNlC7CqG8qCH0sUEj922rDcLouyMvsiMvQHi11/8ay2YNUvAwfKS2OsWn0ngcSFE+qz+EndlbYbvRJ8LUXuOvNH63gysihkKbhVPlkwIOsFMBxDNAyLGIOYIYI65ToTfWT0UMR2RGgMoPGkP9BwklOSehlM0ZpxycBHAiQP6HpW+KGDzGBh5DdcBi7bzh3IUUEUFOeaJckBBMbognIPclnJK/xm9jNJ+uoyfpNcL5zUAMp5JGvzZgCtHCSZ2SI0XqbydFbI2/0vjdDkqGwQbEz6wJfRZKBQbvASEHEjZZ5686RBTEdFlfyHy/FEnAi0SCovyonJMxP+IxJByd2cbOAHB0h0cQcOWXa3O/tlDKG1LAQUAMjZDCppBTDK251GcPjHWP9RDxOhBESV7KCQqksJHjE2bOr/lcGsFz8BnD2vSgyJBMUeJt+Kyhxl9l/G4HJcPAupiU0wc+AfDcEiAc1aHIociBMHJJPAXhE0+CQJh5BhEDEfRjswVReJ1ImHJVvIGAEAKxdL6KbC2Mhe2FO5YzEgL5VBiPQlj1EwbyUkLzsTwEOp3q4SF4j7YIgRjbUGl+Nm+cV68JEw98I3mI1YZC9jQyGFamhsJ3kyMiZygsT0XvUuOvLn63g/IewzYpUkSLQhDAIyHyGGpD8Ai86EFJ7lsoVViljVBJbgkxeAvKc7XhdSAJ0mwzJuvHU0AQH46RO+4vyWPNj4UteQdevkAar/nxKpByoP72ZlTX5KiEYOaE4COFZojA222xqdLGjU8a+B7GpEnoFDnyFoTN1emhsDI9ImJGwvcvR0TKSPiPl2M1/orjdzsoGQadmYjvWTY1GUdzkMImidyQ0k4Y1IbwdhSPgILko3Z2rTolpOA1eEV/oj4fIEZCKCV35MycUwY7l9bGq61QaiKiCKeUhFELpQq1hFs8CISzFmKhVGL5pnTl2A3wG3rAlFtNtc3ckrcYUOgkx+STAJEiD/EWUqbGJLfDHyfvhO8nx2r8FcfvdlAyjO9kPVgRx1n8Yov8cVdWjWcADMTYG0UpASl4E0It5JmyIoKNFzkl15D2Ea+htiMRikeJoZBzZywfbyCvIdCcZZvHUH65Y2fUfEYwqHZOGSCJEwhyy/igOHMndEKKfa8jr8E3MS15PH6LTB7JKQsegodMOOXIbmWKMDokQkbVTx5EBPL9zGpjpMZfcfxuByXDINfimxa+QtyQcLZrJChsep53rDBIGy9dDgCofJRX8eR6vGBhEwYpH95wCtFhJWDwHIRSSOG4jzDKfIRGXvnbZwJLbMTIKZEYHtu6poQcTh84MWEsoRZiIAXPhj7x5VMkYEOhc21aYVObqw0RA0lx8zUQlie0KRN5bMA4paDfdxPDNf6K43c7uMIwFMo0MS9X+PAL64tfUsq6BcCOxKQoFktoBaxtvAQUAtiQEUYBjrewHFNk4HkgEM/CPbwQ5OIx+LyYE4F4Vj2ktfosB+XcmreVpodI4IUO4ZejPuYg341vMHmAbLrY0EVd+dUX4ZPQyY9lLIROqRQBeIflySF5jRhWlycgLuajNf5q43c7KBkGN7E63ggSighT5Ju0cbaMFXMiwAdmhETySY7xzuUl4qYMggiXhFF5DnkQQERR6JvrEVAsVxYsq+blC28+Oacmp+QNKL8EI8ziJSzcCmyssxHj9EEbNXkJNle08ztkPAEk0Z8N2I5wsJHk9GFFgid8O5mIEjnRkwyE7+UlCKdvJ4dFTvzxSo2/uvjdDkqGAQm8DeRDMfLHSFI8PeCNYzw+i5YZSVGbeQ8I67EQ6jmktVOSi4pMLBpSIJyjMyzdNkkzI2G1ORb4CSOfJfODEkImBLR0jQfhjSY5LuRy4kAd3fAMm5rH/p0LXkdrgIHcFOLthynyFO/SxmujwafHeBARozBqL35EDB4DT1LjrzZ+t4OSYaA0oQcrJNQdywsQmlgM8Hy5CAF2fiwCII+wyJEZJwzkovY9P2PVD0X3ZtVHnsJyVhHDd/GrsuDVxlh4Oz0WVhr8q5TbWlN5pB4C5HCGbT8/lPDzR9r2TQeRrbDc1hwQgqcgz7R8U/dp56GxBv/GhVBp3kn55mbjlhEQ88/UZrlnJArsNf5q43c7uNIw6MRRHHkh4KmzGJ6AHO9M4KkT1rBmFGtLsQNdx+/aZc3qb/cU1vA+LM6rd3sDKYlvHEcDH3TxYoWfLfKTQ75+JAQSNgmz2/IEkES+CXi8Dw8Mj7Cta/sgjH663pgZ1lgRISEl4B4hc13eYksbr1V5Dk5aePCcUCArCq/LEwMWVpcnR2r8FcfvdlAyjHVZGAPYUPHKndwQD4A3YLMDKZATTykU7pQXsinaW1SoWxrQpolPg9m8YcExfPIDdELamqyUcGbhTcpyhrys3M7Ayfo5liOMkvPx4Rjhk3BKuIQUe2mja3JI8knAQwp5JqRYWFVY5uUQIZrf9eIhIIIzbEIqIZzNZHumx0jCY4CX/JMjvBp/tfG7HZQMo5ZaavlT+B+r9fQ60AaG/QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/or68kcpc/

The error must be somewhere else.